# Word/phrase for "lingering memory of an unpleasant event"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The first word that came to me was *aftermath*. But it doesn't quite do it. Because aftermath refers to the "lingering" effects and what I'm looking for is the memory, the shadow.

Is there a word/phrase for that?

Comment: The closest I can think of is *remorse*, but that implies a feeling of guilt.

Comment: I hate to over-use the word, Jano, but, "*traumatic*" memory is the closest term that comes readily to mind

Comment: In AmE, we say "*[It] left a bad taste in our mouths*".

Comment: What's wrong with 'shadow' (or 'echo')? "Shadows|Echoes of the event clouded his every waking moment"...

Comment: _haunting memories_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the memory is upsetting:

[Anguish](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Anguish):

> - Agonizing physical or mental pain; torment.

(from TFD)

Comment: I'm not sure that "Anguish" connotes memory or recollection.

Comment: The mental suffering can be originated by a tormenting memory, a regret!!

Answer (score 0):

*Flashback* can be used in that sense - with appropriate context. It is often used to describe vivid, traumatic memories - like those of a soldier, for instance.